# How to know if a fridge would be able to maintain its temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

I would like to understand the thermodynamic relation that exist on a big fridge. If you have any links to help me to more understand the physics relation, it would be nice :)

So here is my problem:

There is an electric charge into a big fridge which dissipates X watts into the fridge. The fridge is said to maintained the temperature at T. with T inferior to the ambient temperature.

I also know the electric power consumed by the fridge, which is equal to E. I do not know the transfer ratio between electric power and "calorific power". If you need to add some value, do not hesitate but the less would be the better :)

And finally, I know what is the input (T_input_liquid) and output liquid temperature T_output_liquid , the throughput F of the calorific liquid.

At the end, we may know what would be the COP needed for stabilizing the temperature T into the fridge for X watts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is an electric charge into a big fridge which dissipates X watts into the fridge.

We'd normally say "electrical energy" into the fridge. It doesn't dissipate heat into the fridge (which would *raise* the temperature - it uses the energy to run a compressor which is located outside the cold compartment.

> I also know the electric power consumed by the fridge, which is equal to E. I do not know the transfer ratio between electric power and "calorific power". If you need to add some value, do not hesitate but the less would be the better :)

I would expect a CoP (coefficient of performance) of about 3. For every 1 watt into the compressor up to 3 watts of cooling (or heat pumping) could be achieved.

> And finally, I know what is the input (T_input_liquid) and output liquid temperature T_output_liquid , the throughput F of the calorific liquid.

It's not important for the calculations we are doing.

> At the end, we may know what would be the COP needed for stabilizing the temperature T into the fridge for X watts.

Temperature will stabilise when cooling power matches the rate of heat leakage *into* the fridge. In refrigeration systems the compressor is oversized and a thermostat is used to switch off the compressor when adequate cooling has been achieved. For your calculations you would need to measure the duty cycle (% on time) of the compressor.